# Frequency components much less prominent at the receiver for multiple tones

Tags: fft, gnuradio

I am trying to transmit a multi-tone signal from one USRP (N210) to another and have written an out of tree block to generate the multi tone signals using an ifft. The two USRPs are connected directly via a cable and a $50\ \Omega, 20\textrm{ dB}$-attenuator.

I am finding that the signal is received clearly for 1 and 2 tones but not for 3+ tones. I'm not sure what I can do digitally to make the frequency components are lot more distinct. The received signal is amplified by $10\textrm{ dB}$ and passed through a LPF and I've attached some FFT plots showing the results.

[image: 2 tone receiver]

[image: 4 tone receiver]

I don't have enough reputation to show the transmitted signals but they are just direct spikes evenly distributed through the bandwidth and very distinct.

The received signals at the USRP are complex and so the FFT plots shown are only the real components.

---

**Flow graph**

[image: Flow graph]

**Relevant graphs for a series of different tones**

- **Single tone**

  Receive:

  [image: single tone received]

  Transmit:

  [image: single tone transmitted]
- **Two tones**

  Receive:

  [image: two tone received]

  Transmit:

  [image: two tone transmit]
- **Three tones**

  Receive:

  [image: 3-tone RX]

  Transmit:

  [image: 3-tone TX]

The number sweep block is an out of tree module that produces the frequency array that is passed into the FFT block.

The two USRPs are connected via a MIMO cable to ensure synchronisation of their clocks.

Comment: that could be due to the spectral characteristics of the signals. Are you sending pure tones or pulse modulated tones?

Comment: From what I know of how the USRP works, I assume the transmitted wave will be pulse modulated (I'm not 100% sure). Its worth noting that I am using an oversampling of 5 (1MHz)

Comment: How many tones are you transmitting, over what bandwidth? What is the duration of each tone?

Comment: why is your spectrum single sided? The USRP gives you complex baseband, so your spectrum should basically span $[-\frac{f_s}2;\frac{f_s}2]$ No, the USRP doesn't do any baseband modulation itself, it just mixes up the baseband signal you supply it with to the carrier frequency you specify. Which is that? Which model is your USRP? If applicable: which daughterboard? can you include the flow graph? This is all very much stumbling in the dark.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm using the USRP N210 with a carrier frequency of 2.8GHz. Yes, the plots do go into the negative frequencies and the fft plots in the question are the real parts of the received complex signal. I've edited the question to include the relevant information that I missed out. I've tried experimenting with different oversampling rates and windows for the fft block and LPF.

Comment: You never should have Throttle in a flow graph with Hardware sinks. In fact, I added a fix to GRC quite a while back that should actually print a warning that you shouldn't do that. It introduces a second clock, and will lead to under/overruns.

Comment: btw, added the pictures for you; with pictures, a really better question! Great work. Another hint for future work: When I post a flow graph on StackExchange, or for a two colum (typical IEEE) paper, I tend to set the canvas size to something like `(600,2000)` so that I get a potrait, and not a landscape canvas :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for the nice comments. The reason why I have a throttle is because my out of tree file sink module at the transmitter doesn't seem to work without it (though that is another issue I am currently looking at). I'll edit my answer so its much more useful to others too. As far as the flowchart is concerned, its a complete mess and has dozens of disabled blocks. I probably should clean it up and use a much more appropriate size. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was from the fact that I was using a rectangular window for the ifft at the transmitter.

Using any other window at the ifft ensures there are no harmonics outside the 200kHz (which are interrupting the signal).

Here is an example of the signal using the rectangular window
[image]

And using a hamming window
[image]

**Four tones**

Received
[image: 4-tone RX]

Transmitted
[image: 4-tone TX]

Comment: you might want to say something why that solves things, mathematically, for the afterworld :)